# Is it possible to install a frost-proof sillcock on a steel plate?

Tags: installation

Is it possible to install a frost-proof sillcock on a steel plate?

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE. Shopping recommendations are off topic here, since prices and availability are too variable to be useful for future askers. If you could clarify your installation question a bit, we may be able to help with that.

Comment: How thick is the steel? In general it's not too difficult to drill through plate steel with a good strong drill.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can install a spigot on virtually any solid surface. If you can't drill fasteners into the material, it may be feasible to use silicone, spray foam, or another substance to anchor the pipe in the hole, making for a solid installation.